# Why Cmake does not have an official toolchain for iOS

Tags: ios, macos, cmake, cross-compiling

Recently I did some cross compiling things with CMake for a library I wrote.

This page [cmake-toolchains](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/manual/cmake-toolchains.7.html) gives a very useful list of official cross compiling support.

However, Darwin, OSx, iOS are missed here. Seems like CMake does not support APPLE things officially though there are many people coding for APPLE.

My questions are:

- Why CMake does not support APPLE platforms?
- Any good tools for doing this to recommend? (like e.g. [Hunter](https://github.com/ruslo/hunter))

Update:

Recent new CMake versions support both Apple desktop and mobile platforms already.

Comment: This is not a question for stack overflow - it does not contain a programming question, and is also asking for a recommended tool. I would hazard a guess that one of the primary reasons **why** cmake would not support _cross-compiling_ with an iOS or OSX target is that the native toolchains are only available on the OSX platform. Hunter looks to need access to an OSX system to compile for those targets leveraging travis-ci for that purpose.

Comment: Yeah, it's a compiling question

Comment: @Petesh Where should I go and ask this question, cause I really want to get some anwsers of these two questions.

Comment: Looking at the [cmake bugtracking site](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/16521) the cmake-toolchains documentation may simply be out of date in relation to iOS cross compilation. I'd ask there about cross compilation and cmake toolchains as they're probably the ones to know about it; and again, asking for a recommended tool is [explicitly called out](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251134/where-can-i-ask-about-finding-a-tool-library-or-favorite-off-site-resource) and you're pointed towards [the software recommendations site](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/).